# sql job runs but does nothing

Tags: sql

I'm running a script as a SQL Job. There are multiple jobs running the same script on multiple databases. The job says it ran correctly and has no errors. It's a database reindexing script. Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: What makes you think the reindexing did not occur?  Is this a built-in maintenance task or a custom script?  If the latter what is it?

Comment: Its a custom script. I know it doesn't run because the script is used to make our software run faster and it doesn't. It runs everyday. If I run it manually then it does work and run faster.